# httpclient with twitter gives me unauthorized 401 strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519

Tags: twitter, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

When using httpClient to connect to twitter I Always get this response

> responseString{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version:
> 1.1, Content:System.Net.Http.StreamContent,  Headers: {   strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519   Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2014
> 00:35:10 UTC   Set-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A139112851013762159;
> Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 31-Jan-2016 00:35:10 UTC
> Server: tfe   Content-Length: 63   Content-Type: application/json;
> charset=utf-8 } }
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

I googled

> strict-transport-security: max-age

found people suggested to change the access setting of the twitter app to Read, Write and Access direct messages, i Did so but nothing changed , so if any one faced the same problem or any body has suggestions , it would be appreciated

Comment: When you get a 401 there should always be a www-authenticate header that tells you what authorization schemes you can use to authorize your request.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons this might happen. I have this question on the LINQ to Twitter FAQ with several suggestions on how to debug:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LINQ%20to%20Twitter%20FAQ

Comment: thank you for your response  , but it seems its not my lucky day , I removed the app and when trying to create another one it gives me "rate limit exceeded". although this is the only app i have. I'll try to create another app and recheck all the notes you sent again.